# How to find $x$ in $y=\frac{x}{x+1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm asking this stupid question because I don't even know what this algabreic step that I'm looking for is called: How to find $x$ in $0.85=\frac{x}{x+1}$?

It's maddening. I think I used to be able to do this…

I'll already be very satisfied if somobody can mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: How about cross multiplying, taking all $x$'s to one side, numbers to another ?

Comment: Can you elaborate? The part that I forgot is how to separate the $x$s from the 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y = \frac{x}{x+1}\\
y(x+1) = x\\
xy + y = x\\
x - xy = y\\
x(1-y) = y\\
x= \frac{y}{1-y}$$

$y = 0.85\implies x = \frac{0.85}{1-0.85} = \frac{17}3$

Answer (score 4):

You have that:

$$0.85 = \frac{x}{x+1}$$

**The trick here is to multiply the denominator of the fraction on both sides to get rid of it:**

$$(x+1)*0.85 = \frac{x}{x+1}*(x+1)$$
$$0.85(x+1) = x$$
$$0.85x + 0.85 = x$$
$$0.15x = 0.85$$
$$x = \frac{17}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer such a basic question.

Comment: @BigSmoke no problem! Always happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

If $y = \frac {x} {x + 1}$, then $x = \frac {y} {1 - y}$ after rearranging the terms.

Answer (score 2):

$0.85(x+1)=x$ so $0.85x+0.85=x$ therefore $0.85=0.15x$ so $x=\frac{0.85}{0.15}$ hence $x=\frac{17}{3}$